# How sort a value inside a map looping in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, sorting

I am learning React JS and for that I am replicating a website that I developed in PHP. And I got to a certain point that a question arose that I am not finding in my internet searches. I'm using Axios to take data from the database and present it on the front end. the result I create a State and use the map () to create a loop, so far so good, but I would like to order this result by a value that is returned by the map ().

I have the return of a field called votes which are numbers that I want to use it to sort the result.

Follow the codes

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    places: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:1337/places/')
      .then((res) => this.setState({ places: res.data }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.places[0]);
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <section id='places'>
          <div className='container'>
            <Places places={this.state.places} />
          </div>
        </section>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Places.js

```
class Places extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.places
      .sort((a, b) => a.votos > b.votos)
      .map((place) => (
        <div className='row' key={place.id}>
          <div className='col-lg-4'>
            <Card key={place.id} place={place} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ));
  }
}
```

I even tried using sort (), but I don't know how to choose a particular field to use as a reference for sort ()

Thanks

Comment: `a.votos`? Is that a typo? I saw you mentioned before `I have the return of a field called votes`.

Comment: Chenxsan It is only the translation of votes in my language (Portuguese), to facilitate. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You were not far from it. sort expects numbers returned, not booleans:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.votos > b.votos) {
      return 1
  }
  if (a.votos < b.votos) {
      return -1
  }

  // they are equal
  return 0
  })
```

If votos is an int, you can just return a.votos - b.votos like this:

```
.sort((a, b) => a.votos - b.votos)
```

Comment: Thanks Salmin. I use .sort(a, b) => b.votes - a.votes and works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a.votos > b.votos. Use a.votos - b.votos.

```
class Places extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.places
      .sort((a, b) => a.votos - b.votos)
      .map((place) => (
        <div className='row' key={place.id}>
          <div className='col-lg-4'>
            <Card key={place.id} place={place} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ));
  }
}
```

Here is some more info from MDN:

- > If compareFunction is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to compareFunction). If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
- > If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
- > If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behavior, thus, not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
- > If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a (i.e. b comes first).
  >   compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned, then the sort order is undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Hi Kyler. Using a.votos - b.votos makes the sort, but I want from the biggest to the smallest, if I change the order will it work? Type b.votes - a.votes? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, using b.votes - a.votes would reverse it. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use > or < sign in sort. As sort expects a number to be returned against each iteration. For more information please read MDN documentation,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

If votes property is number, you can use following code. It will sort your array by ascending order.

```
.sort((a, b) => a.votos - b.votos)
```

If your votes property is string, you can use following ternary operator code like this,

```
.sort((a, b) => a.votos > b.votos ? 1 : -1)
```